# Is it possible to show different prices in different currency to different users based on their geolocation/IP resolution

Tags: magento-1.9, price

Example:

I want to show the price of same product in same store in $ if a customer from USA is accessing the site and show the price in GBP if a customer is accessing the site from UK.

The price shown can be based on exchange rate or even static.I am using version 1.9
Thanks

Comment: please mention magento version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at this answer you can find how you can get country by Ip

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553160/getting-visitors-country-from-their-ip

So logic for this is quite simple .

create multiple store based on currency and switch user store according to their country(IP)

you can write this logic in `controller_action_predispatch` event  where you can check user ip and country and change users store based on IP

Answer (score 0):

Magento default does not support this feature because once you set price for a product, this price is applied for the whole website regardingless which store view your customers are in. Therefore, if you want your US customers see the price of a product in $ and UK customers see this price in GBP, you need help from an extension which can allow you set up different prices of a products for each store view.

Let's look for an extension on Magento Connect. I try and find out this one: 
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multiple-store-view-pricing.html

It has a feature that allows setting up prices of product per store view. You can take it as a consideration. In addition, you also can find out some other extensions that can support you this issue. Try to seek for them on Magento Connect

Answer (score 0):

I think below module can suite your requirement:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/auto-currency-switcher-1-1.html

If above module does not work as expected and if you are developer, then you can follow below tutorial:

http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/how-to-set-default-store-currency-based-on-visitor-country-in-magento/

I hope one of above solutions can surely help you.

Please let me know if you find any problem.